# How to change Done Button Title on SFSafariviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to change the done button title appearance on `SFSafariViewController` navigation bar (iOS9.0 greater Versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SFSafariViewController/initWithURL:) documentation on SFSafariViewController, there does not appear to be a publicly-accessible way to change the title of the Done button.

If you want customised in app browser in iOS,Just use Some other WebView Browsers example like [wkWebView](http://www.appcoda.com/webkit-framework-intro/).(If Browser was used to google sign in api we need [Oauth2](https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/implementing-an-oauth2-login-flow-in-wkwebview-de74e23fe9ee#.9557yzwg2) process)

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/dismissbuttonstyle
From iOS 11 onwards we have option to choose the button style from below 3 options:
case done

case close

case cancel

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Short answers with a url are considered low quality as the url link can break or its contents can change. You need to include the key details in your SO post.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change Done button color but if you want to change Done button title then you must have to implement manual button at run time

change Done button color using this code

```
SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:webpageUrl];
[safariViewController.view setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: How did you add manual button at run time?..SFSafriviewController will handled by internally...if Possible post your code..