# how to change "done" button title of uiwebview keyboard toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

Is there a way to change the title of the done button on the UIWebView keyboard toolbar?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958918/how-to-change-done-button-title-on-sfsafariviewcontroller) but it's about SFSafariViewController
[image]

Comment: See this many help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33483204/6393522

Comment: @SaraMethuz This is about changing the color of the button, not the title.

Comment: @the4kman this question-related SFSafariViewController that way I am providing this link

Comment: @SaraMethuz how this question related to SFSafariViewController and to color? i am talking about the title

Comment: Hope this will help you, https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls