# Keyboard "Done" not displaying when wrap on Material App in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-keyboard

I am using this library `keyboard_actions` to display `Done` button when keyboard displays. Everything was working fine but when i wrap `MediaQuery` above on `MaterialApp` then that `done` button doesn't display when keyboard pops up. **Note: I use this `MediaQuery` for to Restrict the bold text and font size in the app**. So is there any way to fix this issue ?

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'FirstPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window)
          .copyWith(boldText: false),
      child: MaterialApp(
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MediaQuery(
            child: child!,
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
          );
        },
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              'textArea',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
                },
                child: Text('Click'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> FirstPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  final FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();

  KeyboardActionsConfig _buildConfig(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardActionsConfig(
      keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL,
      keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
      nextFocus: true,
      actions: [
        KeyboardActionsItem(
          focusNode: _nodeText1,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FirstPage'),
      ),
      body: KeyboardActions(
        config: _buildConfig(context),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number, focusNode: _nodeText1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @JeelBhatti Yes, like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415852/how-to-change-done-button-title-of-uiwebview-keyboard-toolbar

Comment: Check this solution if any queries asks me.

Answer (score 0):

**Add This Line on top:-**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

[image]

I hope this solution is useful for you and if you want to use a keyboard done button like this.

[image]

You have to add this line on TextField Widget.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
              decimal: true,
              signed: true,
             ),
```

And you can also add input for matters for restricted symbols you don't want.

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`
I add this line at top in `main.dart` and `FirstPage.dart` but still doesn't work.

Comment: restart your application this code working in my mac.

Comment: Yes i also restarted but still doesn't work
By the if i use this line `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` at the top it says unused import. I also updated my code hope you find the solution

Comment: update your package.

Comment: I updated that package to `keyboard_actions: ^3.4.5` but still doesn't work.

Comment: can you upload code in github.

Comment: Did you checked ?